# Is it up to the programmer to deallocate on exit()?

Tags: c, free, valgrind, exit, exit-code

I have a program and when I input wrong data from the keyboard it just exits with `exit(1)`.

I was testing with Valgrind and while this happens there are no errors, but I can see that there are still reachable x bytes.

So my question: Is it up to the programmer to free memory before hitting an `exit()` or is the OS going to take care of it?

Comment: I think you are worrying about something that is taken care of by modern OSs. For instance, in Windows you don't implicitly clean up the GUI - the application's internal structure and the OS takes care of it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea (and in old enough versions of Windows, it was essential), but when a program `exit()`s on modern operating systems its entire address space is reclaimed.

Comment: The one exception is System V / POSIX IPC shared memory, unless it was keyed `IPC_PRIVATE`.

Comment: In general, `free()`ing memory when you are about to exit is a *complete* waste of time on any platform supported by Valgrind, and bad idea(TM). For multithreaded programs, it can also introduce hard-to-catch bugs (unless other threads are joined first).

Answer (score 3):

In the end, the OS will take care of it (on every modern OS, it was not the case with older version of Windows). Every ressource used by your program (memory, open file descriptors, ...) will be reclaimed by the OS when the program terminate (except some resource that are designed to survive process termination, mainly some sort of shared memory / mutex).

However, `valgrind` is here to help you track memory leak and will report every available memory region so that you can, if you want, manually release them.

Comment: but in this case the "bytes reachable" mean that there is a leak or not? from what I understand that portion of the memory can be read and thus there is a leakage even if it's not reported verbally.

Comment: From the application point of view, yes there is a leak since the application didn't _explicitly_ return the memory to the operating system. From the operating system point of view, there isn't because it will reclaim all the memory whether or not `free` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we are talking about user space, I think it is normally safe to assume that it is not an error to leave memory allocated on exit(). However, I consider bad design a program that reaches its end during normal execution and don't deallocate on exit.

Answer (score 0):

It is a *bad* idea to `free` memory before exit()ing. It wastes time for no good reason, and in multithreaded programs it can actually cause bugs if other threads are not joined first and may access some of the allocated memory.

The "still reachable" is *not* a leak. Consider:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void *a_global;
int main() {
  void *a_local = malloc(10);
  a_global = malloc(20);
}

gcc -g t.c && valgrind ./a.out

==12228== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12228== Using Valgrind-3.7.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12228== Command: ./a.out
==12228== 
==12228== 
==12228== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12228==     in use at exit: 30 bytes in 2 blocks
==12228==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 30 bytes allocated
==12228== 
==12228== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12228==    definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==12228==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12228==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12228==    still reachable: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
==12228==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Here, by the time you've reached exit, `a_local` has gone out of scope. There is *no* way to free that memory; it is lost forever. That's a leak.

OTOH, you could easily free `a_global` (you just shouldn't), it's reachable, and is *not* a leak.

Comment: Wait, so you *should* be explicitly freeing `a_local` then?